# Why is my instant search not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/test search/search.html Whats wrong with the code? Try typing anything in there without clicking enter. It used to work... I dont know what the issues are on line 3 and 31. Heres links.xml and livesearch.php

```
onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/test search/links.xml
 onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/test search/livesearch.php
```

Php code

```
    <?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0)
{
$hint="";
for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)
  {
  $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
  $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
  if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1)
    {
    //find a link matching the search text
    if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q))
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {
        $hint="<a href='" . 
        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
        "' target='_blank'>" . 
        $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      else
        {
        $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
        "' target='_blank'>" . 
        $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="")
  {
  $response="no suggestion";
  }
else
  {
  $response=$hint;
  }

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: You need to provide the PHP source.

Comment: Solved sorry. Lol. Forgot to add a opening <link> tag

Comment: DOM tip : ->childNodes->item(0) is ->firstChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an opening `<link>` tag between lines 27 and 28 of links.xml.

Chrome provides a helpful error for me if I go to: http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/test%20search/links.xml

Comment: He/she probably can't accept an answer yet, although you can upvote me... ;)

Comment: i will just have to wait a few min to check

Comment: M Miller other way around :D